# Is it .yaml or .yml?

Tags: yaml, configuration-files, app.yaml

According to [yaml.org](http://www.yaml.org/faq.html), the official file extension is `.yaml`.

Quote:

> #### Is there an official extension for YAML files?
>
> Please use ".yaml" when possible.

However there seems to be a disagreement on the internet on which extension to use. If you look up [examples on the web](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/6-4-stable/config), many of them use the unsanctioned `.yml` extension.

Searching Google returns nearly 3 times as many results for the shorter one.

---

[image]
49,100

---

[image]
15,400

---

So which am I supposed to use? The proper 4 letter extension suggested by the creator, or the 3 letter extension found in the wild west of the internet?

Comment: As of August, 2016, YAML.org's [specification](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) is mature, and was last updated (patched) in 2009. In practice, this staleness greatly lessens the weight of their recommended extension. (BTW, their recommended extension isn't in the specification, naturally.)

Comment: @MarkDBlackwell failed standardization like this isn't really fixable. If people ignored their recommendation before; they'll be even more likely to ignore it if the official recommendation changes.

Comment: Are you using .htm or .html now? If you still stick to .htm, then probably .yml is the right choice for you. Otherwise, you may be better off getting used to using .yaml :-)

Comment: I think the use of two different extensions is a deliberate feature to remind users how poorly designed YAML is!

Comment: Wow, this question didn't get insta-closed as opinion-based. I guess back in 2014 stackoverflow was different.

Answer (score 324, accepted):

The nature and even existence of file extensions is platform-dependent (some obscure platforms don't even have them, remember) -- in other systems they're only conventional (UNIX and its ilk), while in still others they have definite semantics and in some cases specific limits on length or character content (Windows, etc.).

Since the maintainers have asked that you use ".yaml", that's as close to an "official" ruling as you can get, but the habit of [8.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) is hard to get out of (and, appallingly, still occasionally relevant in 2013).

Comment: What's worse is my installation of Notepad++ seems to get this wrong :-(

Comment: 3-letter suffix convention has been obsolete for nearly 2 decades. If anything, I'd argue that the World-Wide Web deprecated it in the 90s. It's offensive that anybody even tries to care. Enough so that I'd file a bug against any piece of software that breaks because of it.

Comment: Wikipedia's [Category:Filename_extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Filename_extensions&oldid=641316501) page lists entries for [.a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.a), [.o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.o) and [.z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.Z). Somehow, it missed [.c and .h](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=C_%28programming_language%29&oldid=734449132). These single-letter extensions help us see that extensions should be as long as necessary, but no longer (to half-quote [A. Einstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein)).

Comment: For those interested: the recommendation to use `.yaml` came as early as [Sep 2006](https://web.archive.org/web/20060924190202/http://yaml.org/faq.html).

Comment: @Dave I will keep your valuable feedback in mind. (*saving your feedback to `DOCUME~1.HTM`.*)

Answer (score 61):

EDIT:

> So which am I supposed to use? The proper 4 letter extension suggested by the creator, or the 3 letter extension found in the wild west of the internet?

This question could be:

1. A request for advice; or
2. A natural expression of that particular emotion which is experienced, while one is observing that some official recommendation is being disregarded—prominently, or even predominantly.

People differ in their predilection for following:

1. Official advice; or
2. The preponderance of practice.

Of course, I am unlikely to influence you, regarding which of these two paths you prefer to take!

In what follows (and, in the spirit of science), I merely make an hypothesis, about what (merely as a matter of fact) led the majority of people to use the 3-letter extension. And, I focus on [efficient causes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?oldid=849945669&title=Four_causes#In_modern_science)

By this, I do not intend moral exhortation. As you may recall, [the fact that something is, does not imply that it should be.](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?oldid=842362762&title=Is%E2%80%93ought_problem)

Whatever your personal inclination, be it to follow one path or the other, I do not object.

(End of edit.)

The suggestion, that this preference (in real life usage) was caused by a 8.3 character DOS-ish limitation, IMO is a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?oldid=732783672&title=Red_herring) (erroneous and misleading).

As of August, 2016, the Google search counts for YML and YAML were approximately 6,000,000 and 4,100,000 (to two digits of precision). Furthermore, the "YAML" count was unfairly high because it included mention of the language by name, beyond its use as an extension.

As of July, 2018, the Google's search counts for YML and YAML were approximately [8,100,000](https://www.google.com/search?q=yml) and [4,100,000](https://www.google.com/search?q=yaml) (again, to two digits of precision). So, in the last two years, YML has essentially doubled in popularity, but YAML has stayed the same.

Another cultural measure is websites which attempt to explain file extensions. For example, on the FilExt website (as of July, 2018), the page for [YAML](http://filext.com/file-extension/YAML) results in: "Ooops! The FILEXT.com database does not have any information on file extension .YAML."

Whereas, it has an entry for [YML](http://filext.com/file-extension/YML), which gives: "YAML...uses a text file and organizes it into a format which is Human-readable. 'database.yml' is a typical example when YAML is used by Ruby on Rails to connect to a database."

As of November, 2014, Wikipedia's article on extension [YML](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?oldid=634957727&title=YML) still stated that ".yml" is "*the* file extension for the YAML file format" (emphasis added). Its [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?oldid=849848710&title=YAML) article lists both extensions, without expressing a preference.

The extension ".yml" is sufficiently clear, is more brief (thus easier to type and recognize), and is much more common.

Of course, both of these extensions could be viewed as abbreviations of a long, possible extension, ".yamlaintmarkuplanguage". But programmers (and users) don't want to type all of that!

Instead, we programmers (and users) want to type as little as possible, and still yet be unambiguous and clear. And we want to see what kind of file it is, as quickly as possible, without reading a longer word. Typing just how many characters accomplishes both of these goals? Isn't the answer three (3)? In other words, YML?

Wikipedia's [Category:Filename_extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?oldid=641316501&title=Category:Filename_extensions) page lists entries for [.a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.a), [.o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.o) and [.Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.Z). Somehow, it missed .c and .h (used by the C language). These example single-letter extensions help us to see that extensions should be as long as necessary, but no longer (to half-quote Albert Einstein).

Instead, notice that, in general, few extensions start with "Y". Commonly, on the other hand, the letter X is used for a great variety of meanings including "cross," "extensible," "extreme," "variable," etc. (e.g. in XML). So starting with "Y" already conveys much information (in terms of information theory), whereas starting with "X" does not.

Linguistically speaking, therefore, the acronym "XML" has (in a way) only two informative letters ("M" and "L"). "YML", instead, has three informative letters ("M", "L" and "Y"). Indeed, the existing set of acronyms beginning with Y seems extremely small. By implication, this is why a four letter YAML file extension feels greatly overspecified.

Perhaps this is why we see in practice that the "linguistic" pressure (in natural use) to lengthen the abbreviation in question to four (4) characters is weak, and the "linguistic" pressure to shorten this abbreviation to three (3) characters is strong.

Purely as a result, probably, of these factors (and not as an official endorsement), I would note that the [YAML.org](http://www.yaml.org/) website's latest news item (from November, 2011) is all about a project written in JavaScript, [JS-YAML](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml), which, itself, internally prefers to use the extension ".yml".

The above-mentioned factors may have been the main ones; nevertheless, all the factors (known or unknown) have resulted in the abbreviated, three (3) character extension becoming the one in predominant use for YAML—despite the inventors' preference.

".YML" seems to be the *de facto* standard. Yet the same inventors were perceptive and correct, about the world's need for a human-readable data language. And we should thank them for providing it.

Comment: [Use file extension ".yml" for YAML](http://markdblackwell.blogspot.com/2013/07/use-file-extension-yml-for-yaml.html) lists many concrete examples, recommendations, and configuration settings defaulting to ".yml" found in the wild.

Comment: If you cite Wikipedia, you better read a little more :[Yaml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML)'s article says 
Filename extension : `.yaml`, `.yml`

Comment: @CharlesFollet, what you quoted was in fact the basis of my statement, "Its YAML article lists both extensions, without prejudice" (now edited to "without expressing a preference"). People use both extensions; yet ".yml" predominates.

Comment: Why did you emphasize "the"? It's very misleading if you just skim the answer. Also, your points seem too weak to warrant a claim that the creators are not "right" imo.

Comment: @confused00 you ask, "Why did you emphasize 'the'?" I indeed did so to highlight that Wikipedia selected the word "the" (the definite article) over "a" (the indefinite article). However—based on your reaction—I've softened my conclusion; after all, YAML's inventors mainly _were_ right.

Comment: Always remember that Wikipedia is a **collaborative** encyclopedia. I edited the YML disambiguation page to reflect that it is just "**a common** extension" instead of "**the** extension".

Comment: Not sure if the number of google results is sublime humor. But note that YML is also the opposite of FML ("F*** My Life"), as per UrbanDictionary.  Those blank google searches are not a valid source of information. You could have used "filetype:..." at least, which would show dominance of "yaml".

Comment: Thx for the good read, except you are wrong. You should use .yaml, http://yaml.org/faq.html. There you have it.

Comment: There has been a domain specific language [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/)  (markup that generates XML) for many years, maybe even as long as YAML. Your Google search count did not count is likely to have counted YML references as well as the faulty YAML references. YAML is not overspecification, it is using the appropriate name to prevent confusion.

Comment: @Anthon Interesting! especially [YSLT – an introduction](http://fdik.org/yml/yslt).

Comment: As of April 1st 2020: filetype:yaml has 231.000 results, while filetype:yml has 652.000 results.
So approximately 75% of the web uses yml over yaml, and that's not a joke.

Answer (score 23):

`.yaml` is apparently the official extension, because some applications fail when using `.yml`. On the other hand I am not familiar with any applications which use YAML code, but fail with a `.yaml` extension.

I just stumbled across this, as I was used to writing `.yml` in Ansible and Docker Compose. Out of habit I used `.yml` when writing Netplan files which failed silently. I finally figured out my mistake. The author of a popular Ansible Galaxy role for Netplan makes the same assumption in his code:

```
- name: Capturing Existing Configurations
  find:
    paths: /etc/netplan
    patterns: "*.yml,*.yaml"
  register: _netplan_configs
```

Yet any files with a `.yml` extension get ignored by Netplan in the same way as files with a `.bak` extension. As Netplan is very quiet, and gives no feedback whatsoever on success, even with `netplan apply --debug`, a config such as `01-netcfg.yml` will fail silently without any meaningful feedback.

Comment: Info related with Netplan issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1815734 and https://github.com/canonical/netplan/pull/106

Comment: Travis CI fails if the file is with the .yaml extension instead of .yml :/ Just spend half an hour on that

Comment: Unfortunately the [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) framework fails with a `.yml` file extension as of now. Additionally, Mr. Sottile, the maintainer, [appears closed](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/702) to accommodating `.yml`.

Comment: GitLab recognizes only YML (for the CICD pipeline config file), Helm recognizes only YAML (for all the Helm chart config files). I'm posting this in regards to the statement "It's official because some applications fail when using `.yml`". ;)

Answer (score 11):

After reading a bunch of people's comments online about this, my first reaction was that this is basically one of those really unimportant debates.  However, my initial interest was to find out the **right** format so I could be consistent with my file naming practice.

Long story short, the creator of YAML are saying `.yaml`, but personally I keep doing `.yml`.  That just makes more sense to **me**.  So I went on the journey to find affirmation and soon enough, I realise that docker uses `.yml` everywhere.  I've been writing `docker-compose.yml` files all this time, while you keep seeing in kubernetes' docs  `kubectl apply -f *.yaml`...

So, in conclusion, both formats are *obviously* accepted and if you are on the other end, (ie: writing systems that receive a YAML file as input) you should allow for both.  That seems like another snake case versus camel case thingy...

Comment: So what makes more sense for you to use for the [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) domain specific language (which has been around for probably as long as YAML): the `.yl`,  `.ym`, or the `.ml` extension?

Comment: Yeah, I always worry about conflicting with some obscure barely known file format... Everyone can make their own file extension, doesn't mean it is popular enough to be concerned about it.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly there is no consensus on this and there will be none at least in years to come.

**SHORT ANSWER**

Use what the software you are working with takes as input. For your own projects you can have your preference of course and you can stick to it.

---

Note different operating systems handle a file extension in a different way. On some having `config.yml` and `config.yaml` next to each other is perfectly fine, on others - not.

I've recently encountered a funny situation, which brought me to this discussion here (one of many :D). This story will reveal that statements such as "YAML/YML is the official one because Google search yields more results for YAML/YML" are not only invalid (mostly because of reality and the fact that searching for YAML yields results that may not talk about the file extension at all but rather talk about the language itself!) but dangerous and can waste a developer's precious time over and over again.

---

**THE STORY**

I was setting up a CICD pipeline with a deployment stage that uses Helm to pull the image I was creating at an earlier stage, deploy it to my Kubernetes cluster and create a service for it. All of this was just to explore how Kubernetes works and what CICD is. I created an empty repo and immediately went to the Web Editor in GitLab for editing the CICD config file. If none is present (the case when you create an empty repo) it offers you a button such as this one:

[image]

What this does is create an example `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in the root of your repo, which is where the CICD mechanism of GitLab looks for its configuration.

Fast forward a couple of days later and I was setting up Helm. Without thinking I went on creating all Helm chart-related files (`Chart`, `values`, `deployment` template and so on).

Running the pipeline (a perfectly valid and simple one) was exhibiting strange behaviour. I was getting an error that `Charts.yaml` cannot be found. I checked. It was there. It took me some time to figure out that it's `YAML` and not `YML` that Helm was asking for. Another try after renaming the file yielded strange error that a value of some sort cannot be found. Funny enough it was the first value I was referencing in my deployment file. And it was because it was `YML` and not `YAML`.

Ok, so in order to keep things consistent (I mean who likes having a bunch of files for the same language with different file extensions in the same repo?) I decide to rename `.gitlab-ci.yml` to `.gitlab-ci.yaml`. This was the last commit I made that evening. The next day I called a colleague and told him that I've set up something that might be useful to him as well and if he would like to check it out. Meeting was arranged and I proceeded doing something else.

During the meeting I told him that I will just commit something (sharing my screen) in the Flask app I've created as a lab rat (a Hello world app basically) and he can connect to my cluster on IP and port XYZ to see the changes. We were both excited. I committed, pushed my changes to the remote repo and waited...And waited...At some point my colleague asked if he missed something. I said no, you should be able to see the changes already. But there were none. Commit was there (both local and remote history showed it) but the remote repo's pipeline was not being triggered, no jobs being executed and no upgrade of the image and deployment. The meeting was over.

Took me half an hour to figure the problem. GitLab does not like `.yaml` for the `.gitlab-ci` file. It recognizes only `.yml`. I figured this out by going to the Web editor and trying to edit the pipeline there just to be greeted by the button I've posted above. I then decided to click on it and just copy-paste my old pipeline. It worked. But now I had `.gitlab-ci.yml` and `.gitlab-ci.yaml` in the root of the repo. Only the `.yml` version was working of course.

---

I visited several discussions like this both on GitLab and Helm to see if it's just me who is annoyed by this behaviour. One thing that was pointed out in the Helm GitHub issue regarding this was that if you have one YAML and one YML file, which one should have the higher priority? I posted this on GitLab (same issue there of course :D) and pointed out that then this would open a whole new debate, where people would argue whether YAML or YML should be used if both present, thus creating a chicken-and-egg problem.