# ERROR - Config value: 'theme'. Error: Unrecognised theme name:

Tags: mkdocs

The solution to similar issues on Github about this all point to installing MkDocs or the theme with a package manager and not pip. However, I have installed both with pip.

1. Installed MkDocs with pip (not a package manager)
2. Installed n number of MkDocs themes with pip
3. updated mkdocs.yaml to add:

```
theme:
   name: '{name_of_theme}'
```

4. then

```
mkdocs serve
```

5. result

```
ERROR   -  Config value: 'theme'. Error: Unrecognised theme name: '{name_of_theme}'. The available installed themes are: mkdocs, readthedocs
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does `pip freeze` list the themes you installed? If not, then they are not actually installed. If they are listed, then the issue may be related to version incompatibilities or something. I expect we'll need more information.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem with mkdocs-material. In my case this originated from a faulty installation of the theme. From the [mkdocs-material FAQ](https://mrkeo.github.io/troubleshooting/):

1. Check if mkdoc is correctly installed: `mkdocs --version`. You should get the version and installed path back.
2. Check if the theme is correctly installed: `mkdocs serve --help`. You should get a list of parameters. Check this entry if you theme name appears:
   `-t, --theme [material|mkdocs|readthedocs]` (in this case "`material`")

If your theme name is missing, try reinstalling it. In my case, I had used the `python -m pip` flag with `mkdocs` and needed to do the same with the theme:

```
python -m pip install mkdocs
python -m pip install mkdocs-material
```

Answer (score 2):

In your mkdocs.yaml, use:

```
theme:
   name: mkdocs
```

or

```
theme:
   name: readthedocs
```

Essentially, the name of a theme you actually installed.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have another version of mkdocs globally installed. That was my case.

I have recently begun using [nala](https://github.com/volitank/nala), a wrapper for `apt`, the package manager for the Debian family of Linux (I'm using Pop!_OS, a variant of Ubuntu). And it has a requirement for `mkdocs` from the distribution's repos, which I just realized.

When I typed `mkdocs` in the terminal, the wrong copy would be launched - the one in `/usr/bin` (actually in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/` according to `mkdocs --version`) instead of the one in my virtual environment. It's curious, because the virtual environment's `bin` folder was supposed to have priority in the `PATH`.

I uninstalled `nala`, which removed the globally installed `mkdocs`, and of course that fixed the problem, but I really like `nala`. I reinstalled it, and after reinstallation, the problem did not return. (Which does not make much sense to me.)

Next time, I will try to deactivate my virtual environment, then reactivate it to see if it fixes the problem. Or else I could check the path for the locally installed `mkdocs` (from the virtual environment) with `which -a mkdocs` and use its full path.

Answer (score -2):

I've never seen the yaml file with the extension ".yaml".
Have you tried changing it to ".yml", so it's "mkdocs.yml".

You can definitely install mkdocs and a theme with pip.

Comment: You can check out (yaml.org)[https://yaml.org/faq.html]. They are recommending `.yaml`. Also checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059124/is-it-yaml-or-yml) post about yaml extensions.