# Data from yaml files in 11ty / eleventy

Tags: javascript, yaml, eleventy

On my 11ty site ([skeleventy-starter](https://github.com/josephdyer/skeleventy)) I want to parse hundreds of reviews. These reviews are stored in my data folder in a folder called reviews as individual yaml-files (named like this: "entry-7128372832.yml"). Each yaml file looks like this:

```
_id: 84494a00-b086-11ea-94d5-7f955bef1b4e
rating: 5
name: Name
review: "review body"
date: "2019-05-12T12:12:31.116Z"
```

I added the custom data file format to the 11ty config as stated in the [documentation](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-custom/#yaml):

```
const yaml = require("js-yaml");

module.exports = (eleventyConfig) => {
  
// Yaml
 eleventyConfig.addDataExtension("yaml", (contents) =>
        yaml.safeLoad(contents)
 );
};
```

However, when I try to loop over the review-data in my .njk-files:

```
{% for review in reviews %}
    <p>{{ review.name }}</p>
    <p>{{ review.rating }}</p>
    <p>{{ review.review }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I neither seem to have access to the data nor get an error in the console. What am I missing here? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You need to change the file extensions for all of the `_data/entry-*.yml` files to use the `.yaml` extension (note the additional `a`).**

The official file extension recommended by the YAML team is `.yaml`; however, `.yml` is also common out in the wild (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059124/is-it-yaml-or-yml) for a quick dive).

The code sample for YAML support in the [Custom Data File Format docs](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-custom/) is written to support the official `.yaml` extension.

In this line of your 11ty config `"yaml"` represents a literal file extension to support, not just the name of the colloquial name of the language:

```js
eleventyConfig.addDataExtension("yaml", (contents) =>
```

If you want to expose both `.yml` and `.yaml` files in your `_data/` directory, this will work:

```js
eleventyConfig.addDataExtension('yaml', contents => yaml.safeLoad(contents))
eleventyConfig.addDataExtension('yml', contents => yaml.safeLoad(contents))
```

Note that the order of code above affects the [11ty Data Cascade](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-custom/#ordering-in-the-data-cascade). If there were a priority clash between a `.yaml` and a `.yml` file, `.yml` would win because the extension is added later.

Also important: 11ty just [recently](https://github.com/11ty/eleventy/pull/798) added YAML support in [v0.10.0](https://github.com/11ty/eleventy/milestone/30), so be sure you are at version 0.10.0 or higher.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the solution. I also want to point out that if you want to loop over a directory of files you need to do it like this ```{% for key, val in subdata %} {{ key }} {% endfor %}``` https://github.com/11ty/eleventy/issues/304#issuecomment-440678396

Comment: Awesome! This got me too, i have `.yml` in muscle memory for some reason :)

Comment: What do you mean by "default YAML support"? The Eleventy [documentation](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-custom/#yaml) still writes about using `require("js-yaml")` and `addDataExtension`.

Comment: @AlexVang I read that again - no idea why "default" was in there. Probably too much caffeine. I meant to say that support for YAML was recently added. Edited my answer.