# "Missing CI config file" message on run pipeline, but .gitlab-ci.yml exists

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

3 screenshots to explain the issue

When I run the pipeline I've an error...
[image: error message saying "Missing CI config file"]

But the file exists

[image: But the file exists]

And it's good

[image]

Comment: What's inside the file? I observed this behavior with empty .gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: @DenisPalashevskii the file is good. It's really weird

Comment: Weird indeed. Another idea I have - is `qa` the default branch in the repo? There is an issue (although closed) https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/43266, probably it's somehow related.

Comment: @DenisPalashevskii Really thank you for your suggestions but I tried with qa as default branch and master as well.. but nothing. Of course ci is in master.

Comment: Last idea, but, honestly, quite unlikely one: GitLab allows to set custom CI/CD configuration file location (Settings > CI/CD > General Pipelines). If it's not changed and pointing at the root of the repository - I would say that this is a bug and it should be reported to GitLab support, otherwise everything looks ok and should totally work

Comment: OMG... A colleague of mine changed it... Everything worked fine since my last deploy... Great @DenisPalashevskii I love you :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. GitLab shows this error message when trying to execute an empty `.gitlab-ci.yml` file
2. Check your configured `.gitlab-ci.yml` file location (Settings > CI/CD > General Pipelines), make sure that it points to the correct place in the repository

Comment: In my case I had a leading whitespace in config filename. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me also when I was specifying the .gitlab-ci.yml in a .yAml format, I am not exactly sure why this happens. I have tried to understand the difference between the two reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059124/is-it-yaml-or-yml) but it seems there should be no differences. I lost 30 min because of this, hope I can save someone else time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I incorrectly assumed that `glab` would run a pipeline for the current branch.

I was running `glab cli run` on `branch-1` which *did* have a `.gitlab-ci.yml`. But it was trying to run a pipeline for `master`, which didn't have a `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

`glab cli run -b branch-1` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this by googling the same issue. The answers listed here didn't help, so I thought it's worth adding what was wrong in my case.

The culprit was the leading whitespace accidentally copy-pasted into the file name. That is, I had  `.gitlab-ci.yml` instead of `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

During investigation I realized that there was an indication that something is wrong with the file name after all. It was the icon next to the file name, which corresponds to a regular YAML file, not a GitLab CI pipeline configuration:

[image]

This eventually helped looking into the right direction.